# Sentinel-5 Data gap

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-5p, gap, air-quality

I am trying to use Sentinel-5P products for air pollution analysis. Although the the satellite has daily coverage resolution, still there are some missed data in some days. It is mentioned in product description that S5P can observe in both clear and cloudy conditions. But why still there are missed data?

Answer (score 1):

Bad things happen to good data. For example, a quick search for "Sentinel 5P missing data finds things like this:

https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/-/quality-degradation-in-copernicus-sentinel-5p-products-due-to-missing-auxiliary-data

which says "06 August 2021: Due to a ground segment anomaly regarding the availability of auxiliary data from Suomi-NPP, the Copernicus Sentinel-5P CH4 products from orbit 19722 to 19737 will not be processed."

The "ground segment" means the receiving station on the ground and all its components. The exact nature of the "anomaly"? Don't know. Seems to be related to Suomi-NPP, another satellite.

Looking at the Sentinel web site shows that this sort of thing does happen occasionally to the satellites, and data gets lost.